# Regarding Approving a Suggest Edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I think I made a mistake:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16234983/revisions

I thought I was just editing the code, so I added the 4 spaces to apply code formatting.

Then I realize the `Community` suggested edit removed the original question and put a query instead. Then I looked to his profile and realized `Community` is a bot or something?

But now I'm not sure if should support `Community` or rollback the suggested edit because the use of `rownumber` isn't even correct on that code.

Comment: Yes, but `comunity` isnt a real user, or at least that say his profile.

Comment: @ryanyuyu My question is regarding if `Community` suggest is ok or not. because doesnt make much sense to me.

Comment: No, that edit was not okay; it replaced the question with an answer. If you look at the [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9478505), both of the reviewers before you voted to reject it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza my bad, I misinterpreted you question.  My other comments aren't really relevant to your question.

Comment: When you see an edit suggested by "Community" that just means it was suggested by a user who either isn't logged in or doesn't have an account. You don't ever have to agree with an edit just because it says "Community" and has a diamond- That's just the account that takes credit for anonymous edits, among other things.

Comment: @Kendra How can you suggest edit without beign logged? I rememenber I couldnt even post comment in other users post when I start

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Anyone can suggest an edit- The edit link is only disabled in two scenarios: A user with less than 2k rep lands on a question with a pending suggested edit (A 2k+ user that clicks the link then is taken to the review page for that edit) or a user with less than 2k rep on meta (there are no suggested edits on meta.) You can check this yourself by going incognito the next time you find a question on SO you wish to edit. (Comments are not peer reviewed like suggested edits are. This is why you need rep to post them- To prevent spam comments.)

Comment: @Kendra: The edit link is also disabled on locked posts and on deleted questions. But those are largely beside your good points.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I _knew_ I forgot some scenario somewhere! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What happen was a user made an edit to change the question from

> How to find `third or nth` maximum salary from salary `table(EmpID,EmpName,EmpSalary)` in Optimized way?

To

> select * 
>   from (select emp1.*,
>                rownum rw 
>         from (select * 
>               from employee 
>               order by salary desc
>              ) emp1
>        ) 
>   where rw=3;

You decided to improve the edit to format the code correctly so the suggested edit then was automatically approved and then committed by the [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user and then your edit was applied.

That being said you should not have approved that edit.

> select * 
>   from (select emp1.*,
>                rownum rw 
>         from (select * 
>               from employee 
>               order by salary desc
>              ) emp1
>        ) 
>   where rw=3;

Is not a question as there is just a block of code and completely it changed what the question was asking.  The question wants the 3rd or Nth but the editor gave the OP a possible answer for the 3rd max and their edit comment was:

> Please see the code , It may help you to find 3rd max salary.

You should have rejected it for

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Or

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

One a side note I looked through some of your edit reviews and I just want to point out a couple that I would of handled differently.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9478854

  - This edit helped bring the post along but It should have been improved more.  There is capitilization that needs to be done and the `1000 thanks` should be removed.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9350090

  - removing the `less than` changes the meaning of the question and should not have been removed

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I fix the second one. The first one I remember even looking for some dictionary to see if make sense. But yes I have to make an extra effort with capitalization. But if you Glorfindel edit still make my own mistakes

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Don't be two worried about a mistake or two.  No one is perfect and I know I have made some mistakes.  I am just trying to help you to be a better reviewer/editor.